# C formating String

Tags: c, string, formatting, char, scanf

I have functin and input like this

```
"{ \'Carl Weber Maria von\', \'weber\', 2 }\n"
"{ \'Carl-Maria von Weber\', \'weber\', 4 }\n"
"{ \'Chuck Norris\', \'norrischuck\', 100 }";
```

It creates outputi like this:

```
Chuck Norris
,
norrischuck
,
100
}{
```

How can I make sure that no characters like {}, are stored in my field.Somehow I can't modify this function to achieve the desired result. Thank you in advance for the answers. Function:

```
int fillPoints  (FILE *fp, TSTUDENTLIST *l)
{
    char *src;  
        char a[2000];
        src=a;
        
        fscanf(fp,"%[^\"]s",src);
    
        int count=1000;
        char output[1000][1000];    
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count) {
            const char *start;
            int len;
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*src))
                src++;
            if (*src == '\0')
                break;
            if (*src == '\'') {
                start = ++src;
                len = strcspn(src, "\'");
                src += len;
                if (*src == '\'')
                    src++;
            } else
            if (*src == '\"') {
                start = ++src;
                len = strcspn(src, "\"");
                src += len;
                if (*src == '\"')
                    src++;
            } else {
                start = src;
                len = strcspn(src, " \t\f\v\r\n");
                src += len;
            }
            snprintf(output[i], sizeof(output[i]), "%.*s", len, start);
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Generally, when processing one line at a time, it is easier to use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) than `fscanf`. If you want, you can always use [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) afterwards on the line contents returned by `fgets`.

Comment: Is the `\n` in your input a newline character in your file? Or is it a literal backspace and letter `n`? Also, do the `"` characters actually exist in the file or did you put them there, to mark the start and end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I suggest you do it in multiple passes over each line, where each pass copies part of the line into temporary array.

For example an initial pass to remove a trailing semi-colon if one exists (for this you don't actually need to copy). Then a pass to copy all but the opening and closing double-quotes `"`. Then one pass for the braces. And one pass for the back-slashes (and the `n` in `\n`). And a last pass for the single quotes.

All that should leave you with something like `"Chuck Norris, norrischuck, 100"`. And this can be fed to [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to "tokenize" on the comma, and you simply call it twice to get the three separate strings `"Chuck Norris"`, `"norrischuck"`, and `"100"`. The last you could pass to [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) to convert to an integer.

You can of course combine all the passes into a single pass once you get the long multi-pass solution working.

---

When I say you make a "pass" over the input, I mean you iterate over the string, copying all but the unwanted characters to a new temporary array.

For example:

```
// Previous pass puts its output in pass_1_output

// Pass to remove double-quotes
char pass_2_ouput[1000] = { 0 };  // Zero-initialize, which is the string terminator

for (size_t in = 0, out = 0; pass_1_output[in] != '\0'; ++in)
{
    if (pass_1_input[in] != '"')
    {
        // Not a double-quote, copy the input to the output
        pass_2_output[out++] = pass_1_input[i];
    }
}

// After the above loop, pass_2_output will contain the same contents as
// pass_1_output, *except* any double-quotes
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but somehow I'm not able to implement this, for this moment I need a quick solution to my problem, wouldn't it be a bit appropriate to modify my code a bit?